# Javascript usando navegador do celular não executa

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho um javascript que faz a formatação de campos do formulário, ele funciona bem mais no celular não funciona.

Agradeço a ajuda

```html
<script>

      function formatar(mascara, documento) {
        var i = documento.value.length;
        var saida = mascara.substring(0, 1);
        var texto = mascara.substring(i)

        if (texto.substring(0, 1) != saida) {
            documento.value += texto.substring(0, 1);
        }
    }

</script>



        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="14" OnKeyPress="formatar('###.###.###-##', this)" class="form-control" id="cpf" placeholder="Digite um valor...">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dei uma olhada rápida aqui e vi que nesse caso o melhor seria utilizar os eventos [`onkeydown`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) ou o [`onkeyup`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) no lugar do `onkeypress`, segundo relatos obtidos nos seguintes links: [keypress not raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055270/javascript-keypress-event-not-raised-on-android-browser),[keypress not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473950/keypress-event-not-firing-in-android-mobile). Existe alguma incompatibilidade com algumas versões específicas do android e do navegador.